# how to return token from graphql mutation

Tags: jwt, graphql

This is my code of mutation in which i use the type of User which has name,email,password and i make two mutations for the register the user and login the user. I have searched all the docs about the graphql and read all the blogs related to authentication but can't got the answer to return the token from the mutation

```
    const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "Mutation",
      fields: {
        addUser: {
          type: UserType,
          args: {
            name: { type: GraphQLString },
            email: { type: GraphQLString },
            password: { type: GraphQLString },
            avatar: { type: GraphQLString }
          },
          resolve(parentValue, args) {
            const avatar = gravatar.url(args.email);
            return bcrypt
              .hash(args.password, 10)
              .then(hash => {
               args.password = hash;
               const newUser = new User({
                  name: args.name,
                  email: args.email,
                  password: args.password,
                  avatar
                });
                return newUser
                  .save()
                  .then(user => user)
                  .catch(e => e);
              })
               .catch(e => e);
          }
        },
        login: {
          name: "Login",

          type: UserType,
          args: {
            email: { type: GraphQLString },
            password: { type: GraphQLString }
          },
          resolve(parentValue, args, context) {
            return User.findOne({ email: args.email })
              .then(user => {
                if (user) {
                  return bcrypt
                    .compare(args.password, user.password)
                    .then(isValid => {
                      if (!isValid) {
                        throw new Error({ message: "password Incrrect" });
                      } else {
                        const token = jwt.sign(
                          { name: user.name, id: user.id },
                          "mySecret"
                        );
                        return user;
                      }
                    })
                    .catch(e => e);
                } else {
                  throw new Error({ message: "email Incorrect" });
                }
              })
              .catch(e => e);
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

This is my User Type

```
    const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "User",
      fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
        avatar: { type: GraphQLString }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to update your `UserType` by removing the password field and add a token field like:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "User",
      fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        avatar: { type: GraphQLString },
        token: { type: GraphQLString }
      }
 });
```

The reason is that `UserType` is a return type of the mutation, so it's "public", and maybe we should not send a password to public(as we are authenticating on the server side), but JWT is public, so we can send it back.

And in your `login` mutation add the token into the user object, something like:

```
   login: {
      name: "Login",
      type: UserType,
      args: { email: { type: GraphQLString }, password: { type: GraphQLString } },
      resolve(parentValue, args, context) {
        return User.findOne({ email: args.email })
          .then(user => {
        .........
                    const token = jwt.sign(
                      { name: user.name, id: user.id },
                      "mySecret"
                    );
                    user.token = token;
                    return user;
                  }
        ........
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different type for mutation like this without changing the existing UserType.

```
const UserMutationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    avatar: { type: GraphQLString },
    token: { type: GraphQLString }
  }
});
```

And add this type in mutation

```
login: {
  name: "Login",
  type: UserMutationType,
  args: {},
  resolver(parent,args,context){},
  }
```